# SQLite select statement assertion failure in iOS

Tags: ios, select, sqlite

I get an assertion failiure on this statement;

```
SELECT keyphrase_id, keyphrase, url, googlename FROM keyphrases left join domains on keyphrases.domain_id = domains.domain_id where domain_id = ? and ifnull(keytime,'') != ? order by keyphrase desc;
```

I ran it through a SQL query checker and it highlighted the "!=" bit citing it wasn't correct syntax. This doesn't make sense to me since I was using this statement previously;

```
SELECT keyphrase_id, keyphrase, url, googlename FROM keyphrases left join domains on keyphrases.domain_id = domains.domain_id  where ifnull(keytime,'') != ? order by keyphrase desc;
```

This is how I bind the `where` values;

```
sqlite3_bind_int(selStmt, 1, domain_ID);

sqlite3_bind_text(selStmt, 2, [dateString UTF8String] , -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

I can't work this out at all and it's definitely nothing to do with the database being open or the statement being `nil` when executing etc. since the only component of the method I'm changing is the SQL statement.

Can anyone suggest any possible reasons for this?

Comment: Please show the assertion failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a return code from any `sqlite3` function call that suggests an error, do another call to [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) and look at the error message, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%s err: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

This will tell you what's wrong.

Personally, I would have thought that the reference to `domain_id` in the `where` clause was ambiguous, but the `sqlite3_errmsg` will tell you precisely what's going on.

Comment: That worked nicely and returned an error message saying "err: ambiguous column name: domain_id". How can I fix that statement to make it unambiguous?

Comment: Don't worry, I've fiddled around with it for a bit and managed to get the result I wanted. Thanks for pointing out this useful errmsg function.

Comment: Great. Yeah, when a column is referenced by column name, alone, but could refer to a column from multiple tables in the SQL statement, you just need to preface that reference with the table name, eg "`keyphrases.domain_id`". Glad you got it!